# how to execute two functions one after the other in a arrow function in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i am creating a todo app in react-native , i am trying to remove the given input once the todois added but the function is not getting executed.

addTodo.js

```
    const AddTodo = ({ submitHandler }) => {
      const [text, setText] = useState("");
      const changeHandler = (value) => {
        setText(value);
      };
    
      return (
        <View>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.input}
            placeholder="new todo..."
            onChangeText={changeHandler}
          />
          <Button
            title="Add Todo"
            onPress={() => {
              submitHandler(text), setText("");
            }}
          />
        </View>
      );
    };
    export default AddTodo;
```

App.js

```
    export default function App() {
      const [todo, setTodo] = useState([]);
    
      const pressHandler = (id) => {
        setTodo((prevTodo) => {
          return prevTodo.filter((todo) => todo.id != id);
        });
      };
    
      const submitHandler = (text) => {
        if (text.length > 3) {
          const todoItem = { id: todo.length + 1, text };
          setTodo((prevTodo) => [...prevTodo, todoItem]);
        } else {
          Alert.alert("OOPS!", "todos must be of length minimum 3 character...", [
            { text: "understood", onPress: () => console.log("Alert Pressed") },
          ]);
        }
      };
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Header />
          <View style={styles.content}>
            <AddTodo submitHandler={submitHandler} />
            <View style={styles.list}>
              <FlatList
                keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
                data={todo}
                renderItem={({ item }) => (
                  <Todoitem item={item} pressHandler={pressHandler} />
                )}
              />
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
      );
    }
```

in addTodo.js
in line

```
<Button
        title="Add Todo"
        onPress={() => {
          submitHandler(text), setText("");
        }}
      />
```

i am trying to empty the text typed it is not working i don't understand why it is not working can you help me

Comment: Maybe is because you put a " , " instead of a " ; ".

Answer (score 2):

Nothing in the component depends on `text` as far as I can see so setting the variable to empty string has no meaning. You need to use it in the `TextInput` for it to be visible.

(Also even though in this case the comma doesn’t do anything wrong you shouldn’t use it. Just use a semicolon to separate statements)